# Disable specific manufacturer(s) so that associated products are not visible in front end

Tags: magento-1.8

I know that manufacturer(s) can be removed, but what I would like to do is temporarily **disable** specific manufacturer(s) in my database so that the products associated with them are not visible in the front end.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this script in your root directory and run it. Change the manufacturer name and Change the status when you want to revert them.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); 
$_products->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array(
   'in' => 'YOUR_MFG',
    ));
$storeid = 0; // your store id 0 is the default id


foreach($_products as $_product){
     //change STATUS_DISABLED to STATUS_ENABLED to turn them back on
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($_product->getId(), $storeid, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach! I will test it on my dev server and report back. Thank you, SR

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways in mind:

## Use manufacturer to disable the products

You can write your own module, which filters the products by manufacturer, disables them and saves them again.

## Observer `catalog_product_load_after` and `catalog_product_load_before`

1. Observe the two events, in the `catalog_product_load_after` observer you unset the ID if the manufacturer is the wrong one
2. In `catalog_product_collection_load_before` you add a filter for the manufacturer